# How can I get the elements of a dataframe which are not in another in Pyspark?

Tags: sql, join, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2, and I want to get another dataframe with the elements of df1 which are not in df2. How could I get it?

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of EXCEPT clause in SQL is the next one:

```
df3 = df1.subtract(df2)
```

This way, df3 will store those element in df1 that are not in df2.